# Generating PGP key ring using Bouncy Castle (C#) results in key ID FFFFFFFF

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, openpgp

I try to generate an RSA key pair using Bouncy Castle for C#. I followed the tutorial for Java available at http://bouncycastle-pgp-cookbook.blogspot.de/2013_01_01_archive.html and create a master key and a signing key. My code looks like

```
IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator generator
    = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("RSA");
generator.Init(keyRingParams.RsaParams);

/* Create the master (signing-only) key. */
PgpKeyPair masterKeyPair = new PgpKeyPair(
    PublicKeyAlgorithmTag.RsaSign,
    generator.GenerateKeyPair(),
    DateTime.UtcNow);
Debug.WriteLine("Generated master key with ID "
    + masterKeyPair.KeyId.ToString("X"));

PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator masterSubpckGen
    = new PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
masterSubpckGen.SetKeyFlags(false, PgpKeyFlags.CanSign
    | PgpKeyFlags.CanCertify);
masterSubpckGen.SetPreferredSymmetricAlgorithms(false,
    (from a in keyRingParams.SymmetricAlgorithms
        where a.IsSelected
        select (int) a.Value).ToArray());
masterSubpckGen.SetPreferredHashAlgorithms(false,
    (from a in keyRingParams.HashAlgorithms
        where a.IsSelected
        select (int) a.Value).ToArray());

/* Create a signing and encryption key for daily use. */
PgpKeyPair encKeyPair = new PgpKeyPair(
    PublicKeyAlgorithmTag.RsaGeneral,
    generator.GenerateKeyPair(),
    DateTime.UtcNow);
Debug.WriteLine("Generated encryption key with ID "
    + encKeyPair.KeyId.ToString("X"));

PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator encSubpckGen
    = new PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
encSubpckGen.SetKeyFlags(false, PgpKeyFlags.CanEncryptCommunications
    | PgpKeyFlags.CanEncryptStorage);
masterSubpckGen.SetPreferredSymmetricAlgorithms(false,
    (from a in keyRingParams.SymmetricAlgorithms
        where a.IsSelected
        select (int) a.Value).ToArray());
masterSubpckGen.SetPreferredHashAlgorithms(false,
    (from a in keyRingParams.HashAlgorithms
        where a.IsSelected
        select (int) a.Value).ToArray());

/* Create the key ring. */
PgpKeyRingGenerator keyRingGen = new PgpKeyRingGenerator(
    PgpSignature.DefaultCertification,
    masterKeyPair,
    keyRingParams.Identity,
    keyRingParams.PrivateKeyEncryptionAlgorithm.Value,
    keyRingParams.GetPassword(),
    true,
    masterSubpckGen.Generate(),
    null,
    new SecureRandom());

/* Add encryption subkey. */
keyRingGen.AddSubKey(encKeyPair, encSubpckGen.Generate(), null);

/* Generate the key ring. */
keyRingGen.GenerateSecretKeyRing();
```

The code works so far, the debug output also prints meaningful key IDs. However, if I save the private key to a file and import it to GnuPG, it shows `sec      0s/FFFFFFFF 2013-07-30` for the master key. The encryption key is OK.

Edit: `gpg --list-packet` shows

```
:secret key packet:
        version 4, algo 3, created 1375205303, expires 0
        unknown algorithm 3
```

Algorithm 3 is `PublicKeyAlgorithmTag.RsaSign`, which I assume is OK for a master key (the Java sample does that, too), but GnuPG does not like this...

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance,
Christoph

Comment: It would be helpful if you could provide the equivalent Java code and compare the output to the C# version (and provide the gpg outputs). There are certainly updates to the Java version that have not yet been ported over to C#. If the Java version is correct, updating the C# should be easy. If not, it would be better to address it first in the Java build.

Comment: I have not tried what the output of the Java version is (I have no Java dev env installed). However, it seems rather a problem on the GPG side. It seems GPG does not like `RsaSign` as algorithm. If I create an `RsaGeneral` primary key, everything works.

Answer (score 9):

In case someone else finds this useful for using BouncyCastle with C# (I just needed to do the same as above, but the code sample above was incomplete so I whipped up my own amateurish edited version). **NOTE: This code was compiled and tested with LinqPad**

```
    void Main()
    {
        String Password = "hello world!";
        String Identity = "Slim Shady";

       PgpKeyRingGenerator krgen = generateKeyRingGenerator(Identity, Password);

       // Generate public key ring, dump to file.
       PgpPublicKeyRing pkr = krgen.GeneratePublicKeyRing();
       BufferedStream pubout = new BufferedStream(new FileStream(@"c:\temp\dummy.pkr", System.IO.FileMode.Create));
       pkr.Encode(pubout);
       pubout.Close();

       // Generate private key, dump to file.
       PgpSecretKeyRing skr = krgen.GenerateSecretKeyRing();
       BufferedStream secout = new BufferedStream(new FileStream(@"c:\temp\dummy.skr", System.IO.FileMode.Create));
       skr.Encode(secout);
       secout.Close();

    }

    public static PgpKeyRingGenerator generateKeyRingGenerator(String identity, String password) {

        KeyRingParams keyRingParams = new KeyRingParams();
        keyRingParams.Password = password;
        keyRingParams.Identity = identity;
        keyRingParams.PrivateKeyEncryptionAlgorithm = SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Aes128;
        keyRingParams.SymmetricAlgorithms = new SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag[] {
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Aes256,
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Aes192,
            SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Aes128
        };

        keyRingParams.HashAlgorithms = new HashAlgorithmTag[] {
            HashAlgorithmTag.Sha256,
            HashAlgorithmTag.Sha1,
            HashAlgorithmTag.Sha384,
            HashAlgorithmTag.Sha512,
            HashAlgorithmTag.Sha224,
        };

        IAsymmetricCipherKeyPairGenerator generator
            = GeneratorUtilities.GetKeyPairGenerator("RSA");
        generator.Init(keyRingParams.RsaParams);

        /* Create the master (signing-only) key. */
        PgpKeyPair masterKeyPair = new PgpKeyPair(
            PublicKeyAlgorithmTag.RsaSign,
            generator.GenerateKeyPair(),
            DateTime.UtcNow);
        Debug.WriteLine("Generated master key with ID "
            + masterKeyPair.KeyId.ToString("X"));

        PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator masterSubpckGen
            = new PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
        masterSubpckGen.SetKeyFlags(false, PgpKeyFlags.CanSign
            | PgpKeyFlags.CanCertify);
        masterSubpckGen.SetPreferredSymmetricAlgorithms(false,
            (from a in keyRingParams.SymmetricAlgorithms
                select (int) a).ToArray());
        masterSubpckGen.SetPreferredHashAlgorithms(false,
            (from a in keyRingParams.HashAlgorithms
                select (int) a).ToArray());

        /* Create a signing and encryption key for daily use. */
        PgpKeyPair encKeyPair = new PgpKeyPair(
            PublicKeyAlgorithmTag.RsaGeneral,
            generator.GenerateKeyPair(),
            DateTime.UtcNow);
        Debug.WriteLine("Generated encryption key with ID "
            + encKeyPair.KeyId.ToString("X"));

        PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator encSubpckGen = new PgpSignatureSubpacketGenerator();
        encSubpckGen.SetKeyFlags(false, PgpKeyFlags.CanEncryptCommunications | PgpKeyFlags.CanEncryptStorage);

        masterSubpckGen.SetPreferredSymmetricAlgorithms(false,
            (from a in keyRingParams.SymmetricAlgorithms
                select (int) a).ToArray());
        masterSubpckGen.SetPreferredHashAlgorithms(false,
            (from a in keyRingParams.HashAlgorithms
                select (int) a).ToArray());

        /* Create the key ring. */
        PgpKeyRingGenerator keyRingGen = new PgpKeyRingGenerator(
            PgpSignature.DefaultCertification,
            masterKeyPair,
            keyRingParams.Identity,
            keyRingParams.PrivateKeyEncryptionAlgorithm.Value,
            keyRingParams.GetPassword(),
            true,
            masterSubpckGen.Generate(),
            null,
            new SecureRandom());

        /* Add encryption subkey. */
        keyRingGen.AddSubKey(encKeyPair, encSubpckGen.Generate(), null);

        return keyRingGen;

    }

    // Define other methods and classes here
    class KeyRingParams {

        public SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag? PrivateKeyEncryptionAlgorithm{ get; set; }
        public SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag[] SymmetricAlgorithms{ get; set; }
        public HashAlgorithmTag[] HashAlgorithms{ get; set; }
        public RsaKeyGenerationParameters RsaParams{ get; set; }
        public string Identity{ get; set; }
        public string Password{ get; set; }
        //= EncryptionAlgorithm.NULL;

        public char[] GetPassword() {
            return Password.ToCharArray();
        }

        public KeyRingParams() {
            //Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Tls.EncryptionAlgorithm
            RsaParams = new RsaKeyGenerationParameters(BigInteger.ValueOf(0x10001), new SecureRandom(), 2048, 12);
        }

    }
```

To test this code, I just used another LinqPad script:

```
void Main()
{

    PGPEncryptDecrypt pgp = new PGPEncryptDecrypt();

    string passPhrase = "hello world!";

    //full path to file to encrypt
    string origFilePath = @"c:\Temp\test.txt"; 
    //folder to store encrypted file
    string encryptedFilePath = @"C:\Temp\Output\";
    //folder to store unencrypted file
    string unencryptedFilePath = @"C:\Temp\Output\";
    //path to public key file 
    string publicKeyFile = @"c:\Temp\dummy.pkr";
    //path to private key file (this file should be kept at client, AND in a secure place, far from prying eyes and tinkering hands)
    string privateKeyFile = @"c:\Temp\dummy.skr";

    pgp.Encrypt(origFilePath, publicKeyFile, encryptedFilePath);
    pgp.Decrypt(encryptedFilePath + "test.txt.asc", privateKeyFile, passPhrase, unencryptedFilePath);

}

// Define other methods and classes here
public class PGPEncryptDecrypt
{

   public PGPEncryptDecrypt()
   {

   }

   /**
   * A simple routine that opens a key ring file and loads the first available key suitable for
   * encryption.
   *
   * @param in
   * @return
   * @m_out
   * @
   */
   private static PgpPublicKey ReadPublicKey(Stream inputStream)
   {

       inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream);
       PgpPublicKeyRingBundle pgpPub = new PgpPublicKeyRingBundle(inputStream);
       //
       // we just loop through the collection till we find a key suitable for encryption, in the real
       // world you would probably want to be a bit smarter about this.
       //
       //
       // iterate through the key rings.
       //
       foreach (PgpPublicKeyRing kRing in pgpPub.GetKeyRings())
       {

           foreach (PgpPublicKey k in kRing.GetPublicKeys())
           {

               if (k.IsEncryptionKey)
               {

                   return k;

               }


           }


       }

       throw new ArgumentException("Can't find encryption key in key ring.");

   }

   /**
   * Search a secret key ring collection for a secret key corresponding to
   * keyId if it exists.
   *
   * @param pgpSec a secret key ring collection.
   * @param keyId keyId we want.
   * @param pass passphrase to decrypt secret key with.
   * @return
   */
   private static PgpPrivateKey FindSecretKey(PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec, long keyId, char[] pass)
   {

       PgpSecretKey pgpSecKey = pgpSec.GetSecretKey(keyId);
       if (pgpSecKey == null)
       {

           return null;

       }

       return pgpSecKey.ExtractPrivateKey(pass);

   }

   /**
   * decrypt the passed in message stream
   */
   private static void DecryptFile(Stream inputStream, Stream keyIn, char[] passwd, string defaultFileName, string pathToSaveFile)
   {

       inputStream = PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(inputStream);
       try
       {

           PgpObjectFactory pgpF = new PgpObjectFactory(inputStream);
           PgpEncryptedDataList enc;
           PgpObject o = pgpF.NextPgpObject();
           //
           // the first object might be a PGP marker packet.
           //
           if (o is PgpEncryptedDataList)
           {

               enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)o;

           }

           else
           {

               enc = (PgpEncryptedDataList)pgpF.NextPgpObject();

           }

           //
           // find the secret key
           //
           PgpPrivateKey sKey = null;
           PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pbe = null;
           PgpSecretKeyRingBundle pgpSec = new PgpSecretKeyRingBundle(
           PgpUtilities.GetDecoderStream(keyIn));
           foreach (PgpPublicKeyEncryptedData pked in enc.GetEncryptedDataObjects())
           {

               sKey = FindSecretKey(pgpSec, pked.KeyId, passwd);
               if (sKey != null)
               {

                   pbe = pked;
                   break;

               }


           }

           if (sKey == null)
           {

               throw new ArgumentException("secret key for message not found.");

           }

           Stream clear = pbe.GetDataStream(sKey);
           PgpObjectFactory plainFact = new PgpObjectFactory(clear);
           PgpObject message = plainFact.NextPgpObject();
           if (message is PgpCompressedData)
           {

               PgpCompressedData cData = (PgpCompressedData)message;
               PgpObjectFactory pgpFact = new PgpObjectFactory(cData.GetDataStream());
               message = pgpFact.NextPgpObject();

           }

           if (message is PgpLiteralData)
           {

               PgpLiteralData ld = (PgpLiteralData)message;
               string outFileName = ld.FileName;
               if (outFileName.Length == 0)
               {

                   outFileName = defaultFileName;

               }

               Stream fOut = File.Create(pathToSaveFile + outFileName);
               Stream unc = ld.GetInputStream();
               Streams.PipeAll(unc, fOut);
               fOut.Close();

           }

           else if (message is PgpOnePassSignatureList)
           {

               throw new PgpException("encrypted message contains a signed message - not literal data.");

           }

           else
           {

               throw new PgpException("message is not a simple encrypted file - type unknown.");

           }

           if (pbe.IsIntegrityProtected())
           {

               if (!pbe.Verify())
               {

                   Console.Error.WriteLine("message failed integrity check");

               }

               else
               {

                   Console.Error.WriteLine("message integrity check passed");

               }


           }

           else
           {

               Console.Error.WriteLine("no message integrity check");

           }


       }

       catch (PgpException e)
       {

           Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
           Exception underlyingException = e.InnerException;
           if (underlyingException != null)
           {

               Console.Error.WriteLine(underlyingException.Message);
               Console.Error.WriteLine(underlyingException.StackTrace);

           }


       }


   }

   private static void EncryptFile(Stream outputStream, string fileName, PgpPublicKey encKey, bool armor, bool withIntegrityCheck)
   {

       if (armor)
       {

           outputStream = new ArmoredOutputStream(outputStream);

       }

       try
       {

           MemoryStream bOut = new MemoryStream();
           PgpCompressedDataGenerator comData = new PgpCompressedDataGenerator(
           CompressionAlgorithmTag.Zip);
           PgpUtilities.WriteFileToLiteralData(
           comData.Open(bOut),
           PgpLiteralData.Binary,
           new FileInfo(fileName));
           comData.Close();
           PgpEncryptedDataGenerator cPk = new PgpEncryptedDataGenerator(
           SymmetricKeyAlgorithmTag.Cast5, withIntegrityCheck, new SecureRandom());
           cPk.AddMethod(encKey);
           byte[] bytes = bOut.ToArray();
           Stream cOut = cPk.Open(outputStream, bytes.Length);
           cOut.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
           cOut.Close();
           if (armor)
           {

               outputStream.Close();

           }


       }

       catch (PgpException e)
       {

           Console.Error.WriteLine(e);
           Exception underlyingException = e.InnerException;
           if (underlyingException != null)
           {

               Console.Error.WriteLine(underlyingException.Message);
               Console.Error.WriteLine(underlyingException.StackTrace);

           }


       }


   }

   public void Encrypt(string filePath, string publicKeyFile, string pathToSaveFile)
   {

       Stream keyIn, fos;
       keyIn = File.OpenRead(publicKeyFile);
       string[] fileSplit = filePath.Split('\\');
       string fileName = fileSplit[fileSplit.Length - 1];
       fos = File.Create(pathToSaveFile + fileName + ".asc");
       EncryptFile(fos, filePath, ReadPublicKey(keyIn), true, true);
       keyIn.Close();
       fos.Close();

   }

   public void Decrypt(string filePath, string privateKeyFile, string passPhrase, string pathToSaveFile)
   {

       Stream fin = File.OpenRead(filePath);
       Stream keyIn = File.OpenRead(privateKeyFile);
       DecryptFile(fin, keyIn, passPhrase.ToCharArray(), new FileInfo(filePath).Name + ".out", pathToSaveFile);
       fin.Close();
       keyIn.Close();

   }


}
```

I still haven't done final tests on this, but it all seems to work (so far). For LinqPad, add a reference to **BouncyCastle.1.7.0\lib\Net40-Client\BouncyCastle.Crypto.dll** and my imports are:

```
Microsoft.VisualBasic
Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg
Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.OpenPgp
Org.BouncyCastle.Bcpg.Sig
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Generators
Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters
Org.BouncyCastle.Math
Org.BouncyCastle.Security
System
System.Collections
System.IO
```